# Как подгрузить картинки в WebView?

Tags: java, html, android

Есть простой справочник, детали которого состоят из массивов.

Подгружающаяся информация изначально хранилась в ассетах в **.txt** файлах, показывал с помощью `WebView`. Но были некоторые проблемы с кодировкой, которые решились путем замены **.txt** на **.html**, внутри которого я принудительно указал нужную кодировку. Текст отображается без проблем.

По всем законам html я добавил картинки, которые лежат в той же папке, что и сами html-файлы. Открывая свои файлы в браузерах, все картинки подгружаются без проблем. Так, как мне надо.

Но на андроиде этого совершенно не происходит, и вместо картинки показывается текст, который я устанавливал в html, чтобы тот показывался вместо незагруженного изображения.

Может ли это быть связано с разрешением картинки? Если нет, то имели ли вы такой опыт? Хочу просто совета, указать верный путь, дойду сам.
Пробовал гуглить по десять раз несколько дней подряд, вводя все возможные вариации вопроса. К успеху не привело, как можно видеть.

xml

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

В Java Class использовал это (используя метод для чтения из raw ресурсов):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

В папке с проектом res - raw. В папке raw лежат html файлы и картинки.
html код:

```
<center>
<img src="an.png" alt="Фото пиццы"></center>
```

Comment: пример html файла и дерево папки assets с файлами в ней.

Comment: Добавил. Спасибо.

Comment: советую перенести из папки raw в assets

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sourse, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Нужно указать такой baseURL: `"file:///android_asset/"`